# List of apps from a Google Play Publisher/Developer (Java)

Tags: android, google-play, publisher

How can I get a List of String id's of all apps from a Google Play Publisher/Developer (or rather me)?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play

Comment: @soldforapp  With that I can only show the apps in the playstore (isn't it?), but I don't want that, but the string id of them.

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? where the the apps? if they are in the playstore, you can access them that way. if you want the id, i think thats in the console.

Comment: @soldforapp  I want to get the id's programmatically in my app.